# Htaccess rewrite url to hash anchor on homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to create an htaccess rule for a website i built in codeigniter for an apache web server.

I basically have a one page website which displays sections of the site on the the homepage.

for example...

**http://www.example.com/sales**

**http://www.example.com/portfolio**

...all appear as sections on the homepage so it display on one page only

My plan is to use anchor tags and hashes to direct the user to the right area on the homepage but I can't figure out the correct htaccess rule to modify the url to redirect to the homepage and to the correct anchor point

So my prefered method to do this would be to a rule to redirects to the homepage like so...

`**http://www.example.com/sales**`

redirects to

`**http://www.example.com/#sales**`

And if the url has more directories I need them to go to the highest parent on the home page

for example...

`**http://www.example.com/sales/future/page1**`

redirects to

`**http://www.example.com/#sales**`

I would also need to make sure that i hide the index.php that displays at the beginning of the segment!

Any ideas or alternative suggestion to get this working would be greatly appriciated

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/|$) /#$1 [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question